# Click links to hide/show content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a table listing some comments. Next to the comment there are two links, the `hide` and `show`. So what I want to do is when clicking the right link to change the comment's status with ajax.

```
// inside a loop for showing all comments
<div class="pull-right" class="publish-history-comment">
    <a href="#" data-time="<?= $row->time; ?>" class="publish-history-comment-link" onclick="toggleHistoryNotes('publish');">Publish</a>
</div>
<div class="pull-right" class="hide-history-comment">
    <a href="#" data-time="<?= $row->time; ?>" class="hide-history-comment-link" onclick="toggleHistoryNotes('hide');">Hide</a>
</div>
<?= $row->comment; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleHistoryNotes(status) {
        var link = $('.' + status + '-history-comment-link');
        var time = link.attr('data-time');
        alert(time);
    }
</script>
```

How can I target which link was clicked and do the ajax call to toggle the comment status?

Comment: try maybe `$(this).attr('data-time')`

Comment: Just some additional info: the alert doesn't fire up, but when I click one of the links instead it scrolls up on top of the page

Comment: try add e.preventDefault() to the start

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` to cancel default action of anchor, rest your code should work

Comment: I've added the `e.preventDefault();` but didn't work. Also tried `return false;` at the end but same result

Comment: I did an update on code. Now I get always only the time of the first row

Answer (score 1):

You can change your JQuery to trigged on click on `a` tag. Also, you should add `e.preventDefault();` as this is gonna be click on the `a` tag, and this would prevent default action.

```js
$('.pull-right a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var time = $(this).data('time');
  console.log($(this).text() + ' == ' + time);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-right" class="publish-history-comment">
  <a href="#" data-time="2133124356354" class="publish-history-comment-link">Publish</a>
</div>
<div class="pull-right" class="hide-history-comment">
  <a href="#" data-time="2465433141212123" class="hide-history-comment-link">Hide</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I did an update on code. Now I get always only the time of the first row

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var time = $(this).data('time');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: not downvoter, However `publish-history-comment-link` is assigned to anchor so no need of `.find(a)`

Comment: I did an update on code. Now I get always only the time of the first row

Comment: Ok. Thats great that you got your solution.